# How to dynamic delete a view from a UITableViewCell using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I want to create an app like Twitter. I'm trying to dynamically delete a `subView` from a `UITableViewCell`, and I'm using Auto Layout.

As you know some tweets include images or links and some don't. So I use `tableview.cell.hidden = YES` to hide a cell which does not include images or links, like so:

```
    if(retweetedStatus.text != nil) {
        User *retweetedUser = [retweetedStatus user];
        NSString *strRetweetedStatus = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"@%@:%@",retweetedUser.screenName, retweetedStatus.text];
        cell.retweetedStatusLabel.text = strRetweetedStatus;
        cell.retweetedStatusLabel.hidden = NO;    
    } else {
        cell.retweetedStatusLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
```

So my issue is when a `subView` of cell has the `hidden` property set to `YES` and it is still occupied space. In addition, my dynamic `UITableView` reference [this](http://www.fantageek.com/1468/ios-dynamic-table-view-cells-with-varying-row-height-and-autolayout/) blog.

Could you tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is for iOS 8 you could set this property as automatic:

`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

then, you can do this in your row to hide the view:
Set a height constraint for the view that you are going to hide, so you can make the constraint's contant equal to 0.

`cell.viewToHide.heightConstraint.constant = 0;`

The `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` property will make your row to adjust to the new height.

Comment: Why my viewToHide has not the property of heightConstraint?Thank you!

Comment: Views doesn't have constraints by themselves, you have to set the constraints needed for your view. If you add a constaint to set the height of your view, you could be able to modify the constraint constant attribute to make it 0 and hide the view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hide the unwanted content. You can change the cell height:

1. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method: return the desired height:

:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)((arrCells[indexPath.secion])[indexPath.row]);
    if (cell.retweetedStatus.text)
        return kBigCellHeight;
    else
        return kSmallCellHeight;
}
```

2. When you need to change the height (hide/unhide content in cell), just reload the UITableView:

`[tableView reoladData];`

or just update specific cells:

```
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath1, indexPat2, ...] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I return UITableViewAutomaticDimension property in the method heightForRowAtIndexPath,so I did't calculate the height of cell.Thank you all the same.